# parsing variable from javascript to html twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I started using html twig in Symfony2 and I got the following problem:

```
function goEditConflict(){
    $("#go").on("click", function(){
    id = $("#case_number").val();

    windows.location = {{ path("acf_case_conflict_edit", {"id" : id}) }} ;
    });
}
```

> Variable "id" does not exist in
>   ACFCaseBundle:Shared:caseHierachy.js.twig at line 38

I try to redirect page base on the id variable but I got the error that when I try redirect to `{{ path("acf_case_conflict_edit", {"id" : id}) }}` the variable does not exist.

How can I use a js variable in my twig code?

Comment: This error is about twig variable named `id`. Please check whether such variable is passed to twig template in which you are trying to use it.

Comment: are you trying to use a javascript variable in a twig template function?

Comment: This bundle might help you to generate urls in JS code https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: Yes I try to use a javascript variable in a twig template function. It may sound funny but I really get start with Symfony and I am not sure how js and twig work together.

Answer (score 3):

Your twig will get written before your javascript runs, and as such, it cannot parse the id from the jquery call.  In this case, you are better off using javascript to append the id to a dummy route:

acf_case_conflict.yml:

```
acf_case_conflict_stub:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "Bundle:acf_case_conflict:edit" }
```

twigged out js:

```
function goEditConflict(){
    $("#go").on("click", function(){
    id = $("#case_number").val();
    windows.location = {{ path("acf_case_conflict_stub")}}+"/"+id+"/edit";
    });
}
```

This will write the new js file to have the new location each time the page is rendered.

Comment: Either of the two functions below which use a parameterized twig path function are better than my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
function goEditConflict(){
 $("#go").on("click", function(){
    var url = "{{ path("acf_case_conflict_edit", {"id" : js_id}) }}";

    js_id = $("#case_number").val();
    url = url.replace("id", js_id);
    windows.location = url ;
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following :

```
function goEditConflict(){
    $("#go").on("click", function(){
    id = $("#case_number").val();
    {% set var %}
          id
    {% endset %}
    windows.location = {{ path("acf_case_conflict_edit", {"id" : var}) }} ;
    });
}
```

Comment: Here If you store id into var, it store id into variable var  not value of id variable.